# Show the arithmetic of Fibonacci numbers?

Tags: java, algorithm, fibonacci

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

class NA_False {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int fibonacci = fibo(5);
    System.out.println(fibonacci);
}
static int fibo(int n) {
    if (n == 0 || n == 1) {
        out.println(n);
        return n;
    }
    else {
        int n1 = fibo(n - 1);
        int n2 = fibo(n - 2);
        out.println((n1 + n2) + "=" + n1 + "+" + n2);
        return n1 + n2;
    }
}
}
```

I want to show how we get each Fibonacci number but I get too many unnecessary steps.

Comment: [Look here](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img440/2996/tu2.png)

Answer (score 1):

Using recursion it is pretty simple -

```
public static int fibo(int n){
        if(n == 1 || n == 2){
            return 1;
        }

        return fibo(n-1) + fibo(n -2); 
}
```

Now from your main method you can call it an print it -

```
int fibonacci = fibo(5);
System.out.println(fibonacci);
```

**Update:**  When you want  a step by step result then you may use the following solution using for loop -

```
public class FiboTest{

     public static void main(String[] args){

          int term = fibo(17);
          //1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987 1597
          System.out.println();
          System.out.println("Result: " +term);
     }

     public static int fibo(int n){

          int first = 1;
          int second = 1;
          int third = 0; 
          for(int i=1; i<(n-1); i++){

               third = first+second;
               System.out.println(first +" + "+ second  +" = "+ third);

               //update first and second terms 
               first = second;
               second = third;
          }

          return third;
     }  
}
```

Comment: I think the goal was _not_ to show the result only, but to show each step of the recursive calculation.

Comment: I want to print how each number is added together, for example I want to print that  8 = 5 + 3.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that this is probably the worst possible way to calculate the Fibonacci number. The reason, why you see most additions multiple times is, because you DO caluclate them multiple times.
Usually you would start with fib numbers 1 and 2 and then progress the sequence until you reach the required number.

Answer (score 0):

When you calculate `fibo(n)` recursively, it opens two branches for each call. If we do `fibo(5)`, for example, it does:

```
fibo(5) = fibo(4) + fibo(3)
```

Then it needs to calulcate `fibo(4)`, so it does:

```
fibo(4) = fibo(3) + fibo(2)
```

As you can see, `fibo(3)` is called twice. That's why you will get `2=1+1` printed twice. This will also happen multiple times for `fibo(2)`, `fibo(1)`, etc.

If you want to print each sum only once, you will need to store the values you already calculated or use a different method to calculate the Fibonacci number.

You can do it iteratively with a `for` loop:

```
static int fibo(int n) {
    int p1 = 0;
    int p2 = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int tmp = p1 + p2;
        System.out.println(tmp + "=" + p1 + "+" + p2);
        p1 = p2;
        p2 = tmp;
    }
    return p2;
}
```

Note this returns the sequence in the form `1 1 2 3...`. If you want the form `0 1 1 2 3...` you need to replace `return p2` with `return p1`.